# "erst seit" vs "erst vor"

Tags: meaning, difference, usage, word-order

Is there a difference in meaning and/or usage between

> erst seit

and

> erst vor

regarding time periods? For example, taken from DWDS:

> Das konnten sich die Berliner Theaterdirektoren unmöglich entgehen lassen, und **erst vor wenigen Tagen** wurde auch Fräulein Hartwig ans "Lessingtheater" angagiert, wo ihrer große Aufgaben harren.

> Aber ich bin auch **erst seit zwei Monaten** in Berlin, da kann man nicht allzu viel erwarten.

Comment: Mit "seit" wird eine Zeitspanne angegeben, wobei das Ende die Gegenwart ist. Mit "vor" gibt man einen Zeitpunkt an ohne etwas über die Zeit zwischen dem Zeitpunkt und der Gegenwart auszusagen.

Answer (score 2):

I'm sorry to see after finishing my text that I should have answered in English. There was so much German in the question and in the first response that I didn't realize the questioners language. I cannot do this job in English anyway, so it may be helpful as it is. I think it would not be a good idea to try Google translator mow...

Bei der Frage geht es um den Unterschied zwischen *vor* und *seit*.

Beide Präpositionen setzen zwei Zeitereignisse in eine Vorher-Nachher-Beziehung. Die Nachher-Zeit kann im Text genannt sein oder nicht. Sie ist die "**Anker-Zeit** X0". Unterschied:

- Das mit ***vor + Zeitangabe*** bezeichnete Ereignis ist zum Zeitpunkt der "Anker-Zeit X0" **abgeschlossen** (oder als abgeschlossen vorzustellen). Es antwortet auf die Frage "wann damals?" oder "wann vor Ereignis X0?" oder "wie lange vor Ereignis X0?"
- Das mit ***seit + Zeitangabe*** bezeichnete Ereignis **dauert** zum Zeitpunkt der "Anker-Zeit x0" **weiterhin an**. Es antwortet auf die Frage "seit wann?" oder "seit wie lange?" oder "wie lange schon?"

Beispiele

1. Ich bin **vor zwei Jahren** nach Deutschland gekommen. X0 = unausgesprochenes jetzt, X1 = Ankunft in Deutschland, das Ankommen war zwei Jahre vor jetzt beendet (jedoch nicht der Aufenthalt!).
2. **Drei Monate vor meiner Hochzeit 2018** war mein Vater gestorben. X0 = Zeitpunkt meiner Hochzeit 2018, X1 = drei Monate vorher Tod des Vaters
3. **Vor meiner Schulzeit** verlebte ich eine wunderbare Kindheit bei meinen Großeltern auf dem Land. X0 = Schulzeit, allerhöchstwahrscheinlich Vergangenheit, X1 = schöne Zeit einer Kindheit auf dem Land, mit der Schulzeit beendet, also auch Vergangenheit
4. Ich will **vor dem Studium** noch etwas Geld verdienen, um mir ein Auto zu finanzieren. X0 = Studium in der Zukunft, X1 = Zeit des Geldverdienens, auch in der Zukunft, soll vor dem Studium beendet sein
5. Ich habe **seit meiner Schulzeit** viel wieder vergessen, was ich damals im Matheunterricht gelernt hatte. X0 = (unausgesprochenes) jetzt, X1 = die ganze Zeit seit der Schulzeit damals, die jetzt immer noch andauert; das Ende der Schulzeit war der Beginn dieser (Vergessens-)Zeit.
6. Damals reichte seine Frau die Scheidung ein, da war Franke bereits **seit drei Jahren** viel im Ausland eingesetzt. X0 = Scheidung vor Jahren; X1 = Auslandstätigkeit Frankes, drei Jahre vor der Scheidung begonnen und zum Zeitpunkt der Scheidung anscheinend immer noch fortgesetzt

Vergleiche:

- Ich bin *seit 10 Jahren* nicht mehr in Berlin gewesen. (Das Nicht-mehr-in-Berlin-Sein dauert immer noch an.)
- Ich war *vor 10 Jahren* das letzte Mal in Berlin. (= Zeitpunkt des letzten Aufenthalts dort)

oder

- *Vor 8 Jahren* ist mein Großvater gestorben.
- Mein Großvater ist *seit 8 Jahren* tot.

---

Das "erst" verändert weder die Bedeutung von *vor* noch die von *seit*. Es bezieht sich auf eine (mögliche oder unterstellte) Erwartung des Lesers beim Theater-Beispiel, der vielleicht gedacht hat, dass Frau Hartwig schon lange eingestellt ist, bzw. auf die Erwartung (des Lesers oder einer betroffenen Person), dass der Neuberliner sich dort besser auskennen müsste.

---

Die grammatischen Zeitverhältnisse sind sehr aufwändig zu bestimmen. Darauf habe ich hier verzichtet und einfach einen bildhaften Versuch mit einer "Ankerzeit" unternommen.

In Grammatiken werden unterschieden:

- das **Tempus** des Verbs = seine grammatikalische Form (*gehst, ging, war schon gegangen*)
- das Sprecher-(Hörer-)Hier-und-Jetzt mit seinem Sprechzeitpunkt bzw. seiner **Sprechzeit** (wann hat Merkel das gesagt, an welchem Tag wurde der Vertrag unterschrieben?)
- die **Ereigniszeit** als quasiobjektive, quasi-reale Zeit mit einer bestimmten Zeitdauer (Datum und Uhrzeit und Ort, dokumentiert oder nach Hörensagen; oft sehr ungenau, wenn Menschen aus ihrer Vergangenheit erzählen)
- die **Orientierungszeit** als Bezugszeit von Sätzen zu einer anderen 'Ankerzeit' als der Ausgangszeit (*morgen werde ich ... zwei Tage danach* = nach *morgen*, nicht *nach jetzt*)
- die **Betrachtzeit** als eine innen erlebte Zeit (z.B. wird eine Filmhandlung beim Zuschauen als quasi-jetzt erlebt, oder beim Erzählen der Großeltern wird man innerlich in die Zeit damals versetzt.)

Comment: @user unknown - Okay, werd's korrigieren.

Answer (score 1):

Man gebraucht solche Wendungen meist relativ lax. Die Beispiele kranken daran, dass, sie unterschiedliche Zeiträume und Vorgänge behandeln.

Wenn Du schreibst

> Ich kam erst vor 2 Wochen nach Berlin.

oder

> Ich bin erst seit 2 Wochen in Berlin.

wird man nicht protestieren, auch wenn man weiß, dass es 12 oder 17 Tage sind.

Bei Daten, bei denen Präzision eine Rolle spielen kann, sieht es anders aus:

> Erst seit den Winterferien gilt ein Einreiseverbot.

> Erst vor den Winterferien trat das Einreiseverbot in Kraft.

Die zweite Formulierung lässt offen, wie lange davor das Verbot in Kraft trat. Gewiss erst kurz davor, sonst würde man ja einen anderen Marker verwenden, aber vielleicht doch 1, 2 Tage vorher.

Man kann auch sagen

> Erst mit den Winterferien trat das Verbot in Kraft.

um die Synchronizität der Ereignisse zu betonen.

Bei "wenige Tage" hat man es aber ohnehin mit einem unscharfen Intervall zu tun, da spielt es keine Rolle.

Ein *vor* schließt ansonsten das genannte Intervall mit ein, ein *seit* kann auf der Grenze liegen, und je breiter die Grenze ist, desto bedeutender kann der Unterschied sein:

> Erst seit dem letzten Jahrhundert gibt es Linienflüge in die USA.

> Erst vor dem letzten Jahrundert kamen Linienflüge in die USA auf.

Der erste Satz verneint, dass es im Jahr 1900 Linienflüge gab, aber der zweite Satz würde es bejahen.

Answer (score 0):

#### seit

*Seit* defines the **timespan** between a point of time in the past and today. This corresponds to English *since:*

> *Seit letztem Jahr wohnt sie hier.* "She has been living here since last year."

#### erst seit

*Erst* says that the timespan has begun in the **recent** past and hasn't yet lasted long. This corresponds to English *only* or *just:*

> *Sie lebt erst seit einem Jahr hier.* "She has been living here for just one year." or "She has only been living for a year."

#### vor

*Vor* defines a **point of time** in the past by giving the timespan between that point of time and another point of time, instead of date. This corresponds to English *ago*. If no reference point is given, the reference point is now:

> *Sie ist vor drei Jahren eingezogen.* "She moved in three years ago." (instead of *Sie ist am 6. Februar 2010 eingezogen.* "She moved in on February 6th, 2010.")

#### erst vor

Again, *erst* tells us that the timespan has been brief and the point of time doesn't lie far in the past. Again, this corresponds to English *only:*

> *Sie ist erst vor drei Jahren eingezogen.* "She only moved in three years ago."